# How do I avoid Sonar's "preserve stack trace" violation?

Tags: java

[Sonar](http://www.sonarqube.org/) gives a major violation error ("Preserve Stack Trace") for the following code. Following method is used to throw an exception. What are the steps should I take to overcome this violation?

```
public void exceptionHandler(String exception) throws PhDashException {

    String exceptionMsg = exception.replaceAll("-", "_");

    ExceptionPhDash pHDashExceptionMapper = new ExceptionPhDash();
    try {
        pHDashExceptionMapper = new ObjectMapper().readValue(exceptionMsg, ExceptionPhDash.class);
    } catch (JsonParseException e) {
        LOGGER.info(e.getMessage());
    } catch (JsonMappingException e) {
        LOGGER.info(e.getMessage());
    } catch (IOException e) {
        LOGGER.info(e.getMessage());
    }
    throw new PhDashException(pHDashExceptionMapper.getMessage());
}
```

Comment: Try passing the whole exception to the logger instead of its message.

Comment: @Niks Tyagi - But the best practice is to Avoid printStackTrace()?right?  http://gazelle.ihe.net/sonar/rules/show/pmd:AvoidPrintStackTrace?layout=false

Comment: yes update as LOGGER.info(exception)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've logged each exception; that should be enough as far as preserving information is concerned like below,

```
LOGGER.info("Unexpected Exception has occurred", e);
```

Or You should re throw the `PhDashException` if you can, because, you should be enough as far as preserving information is concerned

```
throw new PhDashException(pHDashExceptionMapper);
```

Comment: But PhDashException use a string parameter.And pHDashExceptionMapper is a customized exception class.  `public class PhDashException extends Exception{

 /**
  * Serial Id.
  */
 private static final long serialVersionUID = -4859242009502871357L;

 public PhDashException(String errorMsg) {

  super(errorMsg);
 }
}
`

Comment: @AmilaIddamalgoda : So, log it properly